# Projection on Epigraph of a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a convex function $h:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, and a point $(x,\alpha) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$, how can I find a closed formula to compute the projection of $(x,\alpha)$ in the epigraph of $h$?

Of course, I expect the formula to be given in terms of abstract entities such as $N_{epi h}((x,\alpha))$ or something like that...

If a closed formula can't be found, is there a way to express it on the form of an inclusion problem or at least a non-restricted optimization problem?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathop{\textrm{argmin}}_{\bar{x},\bar{\alpha}:~h(\bar{x})\leq \bar{\alpha}} \|x-\bar{x}\|_2^2+(\alpha-\bar{\alpha})^2$?

Comment: Well, in my post I didn't put it (might as well edit) but I was actually expecting something given either by a closed formula such as inclusion, or by a non-restrict minimization. This one gives a restricted problem. Anyway I can transform this to unrestricted?

Comment: No, not for general h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any convex subset $H \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$,
the projection $P(x)$ of a point $x$ is characterized by
\begin{equation*}
 \langle P(x) - x , z - P(x) \rangle \ge 0 \quad\forall z \in H.
\end{equation*}
This is, in turn, equivalent to $x - P(x) \in N_H(P(x))$. This gives your desired conclusion.

As pointed out by Michael Grant, you can write your projection problem as a constrained optimization problem.
The optimization w.r.t.\ $\bar\alpha$ can be done explicitely. Indeed, the minimum is achieved for $\bar\alpha = \max(\alpha, h(\bar x))$.
Hence, you obtain
\begin{equation*}
 \min_{\bar x} \| x - \bar x\|^2 + \max(0, h(\bar x) - \alpha)^2.
\end{equation*}
This is a convex optimization problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Optimality Conditions**

$\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\barre}{\bar{\Re}}\newcommand{\epi}{\mathrm{epi}}\newcommand{\proj}{\mathrm{proj}}\newcommand{\minimize}{\mathrm{minimize}}$
Let $f:\Re^n\to\barre$ be a proper, convex, continuous function; 
its epigraph is the nonemtpy convex closed set

\begin{align}
 \epi f = \{(x,\alpha) \in \Re^n\times \Re {}\mid{} f(x) \leq \alpha \}.\tag{1}
\end{align}
For convenience, we define the projection of a pair $(z,\tau)\in\Re^n\times \Re$
onto the epigraph of $f$ as 
\begin{align}
 \Pi_f(z,\tau) = \proj_{\epi f}(z,\tau).\tag{2}
\end{align}

Let $(z,\tau)\in\Re^n\times \Re$; if $(z,\tau)\in\epi f$, then $\Pi_f = I$.
Suppose $(z,\tau)\notin\epi f$. Let $\bar{x}=\bar{x}(z,\tau)$ and $\bar{s}=\bar{s}(z,\tau)$
so that $\Pi_f(z,\tau)=(\bar{x},\bar{s})$; this pair solves the optimization problem
\begin{align}
 \minimize_{x,s:\ f(x)\leq s} \tfrac{1}{2}\|x-z\|^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}(s-\tau)^2.\label{OP}\tag{3}
\end{align}
The KKT conditions for $\bar{x},\bar{s}$ are

\begin{align}
  f(\bar{x}) &\leq \bar{s}\label{eq:kkt:1}\tag{4a}\\
  \exists \bar{y}\geq 0: \bar{y} (f(\bar{x})-\bar{s}) &= 0\label{eq:kkt:2}\tag{4b}\\
  z-\bar{x} &\in \bar{y} \partial f(\bar{x})\label{eq:kkt:3}\tag{4c}\\
  \tau - \bar{s} &= -\bar{y}\label{eq:kkt:4}\tag{4d}.
 \end{align}

Clearly, $\bar{y}>0$ since $(z,\tau)\notin \epi f$.
Then, because of \eqref{eq:kkt:2}, $\bar{s} = f(\bar{x})$ and, because of \eqref{eq:kkt:4}, $\bar{y}=f(\bar{x})-\tau$, so \eqref{eq:kkt:3} becomes

\begin{align}
 z-\bar{x} \in (f(\bar{x})-\tau) \partial f(\bar{x}).\label{eq:optcond}\tag{5}
\end{align}
It might be necessary to employ numerical methods to solve 
the optimality conditions. It is noteworthy that although there is a long list of functions with analytically and explicitly known formulas to compute their proximal operators, the computation of projections on epigraphs is more involved.

**Dual epigraphical projection**

Let us consider again problem \eqref{OP} and introduce the *Lagrangian*

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(x,s,y) = \tfrac{1}{2}\|x-z\|^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}(s-\tau)^2 + y(f(x)-s).\tag{6}
\end{align}

We compute the partial subdifferentials of $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to the primal variables $(x,s)$:

\begin{align}
\partial_x\mathcal{L}(x,s,y) &= x - z + y\partial f(x)\tag{7a}\\
\partial_s\mathcal{L}(x,s,y) &= s - \tau - y.\tag{7b}
\end{align}

The *Lagrangian dual function* $q$  is defined as
$$
q(y) = \inf_{x,s}\mathcal{L}(x,s,y).\tag{8}\label{eq:8}
$$
The optimality conditions for the optimization problem \eqref{eq:8} are $0\in \partial_x\mathcal{L}(x,s,y)$ and $0\in\partial_s\mathcal{L}(x,s,y)$, therefore, $q(y)=\mathcal{L}(x^\star(y), s^\star(y), y)$ with

\begin{align}
 &0 \in x-z+y\partial f(x^\star)\\
 \Leftrightarrow\ &0 \in (I+y\partial f)(x^\star) - z\\
 \Leftrightarrow\ &z \in (I+y\partial f)(x^\star)\\
 \Leftrightarrow\  &x^\star(y) = (I+y\partial f)^{-1}(z)\\
 \Leftrightarrow\  &x^\star(y) = \mathrm{prox}_{yf}(z)\tag{9a}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
s^\star(y) = \tau + y.\tag{9b}
\end{align}

Then, the Lagrangian dual function becomes

\begin{align}
q(y) &= \mathcal{L}(x^\star(y), s^\star(y), y)\\
     &= \tfrac{1}{2}\|\mathrm{prox}_{yf}(z)-z\|^2 + yf(\mathrm{prox}_{yf}(z)) + \tfrac{1}{2}y^2 -(\tau + y)y\\
     &= y (f^y(z) - \tfrac{1}{2}y - \tau),\tag{10}
\end{align}
where $f^y$ is the [Moreau envelope](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/prox_algs.html) function of $f$ with parameter $y$. Then, the *dual problem* is

\begin{align}
\mathrm{maximize}_{y\geq 0}\ q(y).\tag{11}
\end{align}

**Another approach**

We take the infimum which corresponds to problem \eqref{OP} and we have

\begin{align}
&\inf_{x,s: f(x) \leq s} \left\{ \tfrac{1}{2}\|z-x\|^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}(s-\tau)^2\right\}\\
=&\inf_{x,\xi\geq 0: f(x) \leq \tau + \xi} \left\{ \tfrac{1}{2}\|z-x\|^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\xi^2\right\}\\
=&\inf_{x,\xi\geq 0: f(x) - \tau \leq  \xi} \left\{ \tfrac{1}{2}\|z-x\|^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\xi^2\right\}\\
=&\inf_{x} \left\{ \tfrac{1}{2}\|z-x\|^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\max\{0, f(x) - \tau\}^2\right\},
\end{align}

where we have done the converse of an epigraphical relaxation; we define the function $h(x) = \max\{0, f(x) - \tau\}^2$ and notice that this is minimized at

$$
\bar{x} = \operatorname{prox}_{h}(z),
$$

and $\bar{s} = \max\{\tau, f(\bar{x})\}$. This is of course only useful to the extent that $\operatorname{prox}_{h}$ is computable.