# Why it is important to know the projection onto epigraph of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Why, in general, someone should be interested in finding projections onto epigraph(f), where $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a given function? ($X$ Hilbert space).

I heard about that in problems related to convex optimization, but I don't understand why this issue is so important.

I hope someone could help me. Thank you in advance!

${\bf EDIT:}$ I refer to these notes: https://gubner.ece.wisc.edu/notes/ConvexityNotes.pdf

At the end of page 5, the author says that: "Since we will be interested in projections onto epi f , it
is important to have conditions on f under which epi($f$) will be nonempty, closed, and convex." I don't understand why he is interested in that.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: Look at that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143840/projection-on-epigraph-of-a-convex-function Besides the question itself, I see that it is a common problem. My question is: why? Why it is important to know projections onto epigraph?

Comment: I don't believe I have ever seen a (non contrived) problem that requires projecting onto the epigraph. I am wondering why you think it is important. That is what I meant by an example. The referred question has no background.

Comment: @copper.hat I edited the question.

Comment: Perhaps as a step in a proof? The notes are fairly standard convex analysis, but at a quick glance I don't see many uses for projecting onto the epigraph.

Comment: I guess it is related to the fact that he wants to provide the existence of a minimizer in a suitable subset of a Hilbert space, but I don't understand where he uses projections onto epigraph.

Comment: I am with you there :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The projection onto the epigraph can be used to prove the existence of an affine minorant, and also of the fact that the epigraph of the lower semicontinuous convex hull is the closed convex hull of the original epigraph (see, e.g., Bauschke and Combettes' book, Chapter 9).
2. If you know that the function $f$ has a minimizer and $\mu$ is a lower bound for the minimum value, then you could project back and forth between the epigraph and the hyperplane $X\times\{\mu\}$. The ''$X$'' component of the epigraphical projection will converge to a minimizer.
3. Some interesting sets such as the *Lorentz cone* are epigraphs (in this case, of the norm).

Hope this helps. Of course, the question is basically opinion based: Your notion of "important" may well differ from mine.